# What is difference between "activate" and "ngOnInit"?

Tags: typescript, angular

I saw this sample in [Angular 2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide).

If I do this, I would call `this.show();` in `ngOnInit`, while the demo calls it in `activate`.

What is difference between `activate` and `ngOnInit`? Thanks

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit {
  // public properties
  message: string;
  title: string;

  // private fields
  private defaults = {
    title: '',
    message: 'May the Force be with You'
  };
  private toastElement: any;

  // public methods
  activate(message = this.defaults.message, title = this.defaults.title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    this.show();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.toastElement = document.getElementById('toh-toast');
  }

  // private methods
  private hide() {
    this.toastElement.style.opacity = 0;
    window.setTimeout(() => this.toastElement.style.zIndex = 0, 400);
  }
  private show() {
    console.log(this.message);
    this.toastElement.style.opacity = 1;
    this.toastElement.style.zIndex = 9999;
    window.setTimeout(() => this.hide(), 2500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` is an Angular lifecycle method that is called after the inputs are updated the first time (after first `ngOnChanges()`). `activate` is just a custom method and not called by Angular. To be uses it needs to be called by custom code.

Comment: thanks!! if the sample code call `this.activate()` inside of the `ngOnInit()`, then it would be clear. feels kind of misleading